# OR operator in JSONPath?

Tags: json, jsonpath

Using a single JSONPath expression alone, is it possible to do some kind of 'OR' or '||' operator. For example, these two JSONPath boolean expressions work to check the severity of a log JSON file:

```
$..log[?(@.severity == 'WARN')]

$..log[?(@.severity == 'Error')]
```

But I'd like to do something logically similar to:

```
$..log[?(@.severity == 'WARN' or @.severity == 'Error')] //this is not correct
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I could be missing something, but it seems like @Elyas369 nailed it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the JSONPath page](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/):

[,] - Union operator in XPath results in a combination of node sets. JSONPath allows alternate names or array indices as a set.

Try

```
$..log[?(@.severity == 'WARN'), ?(@.severity == 'Error')]
```

Edit: Looks like there is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/issues/detail?id=27) for logical AND and OR operators in which they state that the operators are **not yet supported** by JSONPath.

Comment: Just so others don't get confused: the OR operator is not yet supported by JSONPath and the above code will not work.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using Goessner's parser, you can use the `||` operator within your expression as follows:

```
$..log[?(@.severity == 'WARN' || @.severity == 'Error')]
```

Comment: Works in the NewtonSoft Json library too

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers. In my use case I got it working by combining the two answers from @sirugh and @elyas-bhy.

```
$..log[?(@.severity == 'WARN') || ?(@.severity == 'Error')]
```