# How to select JToken based on multiple name candidates in JSONPath?

Tags: json, json.net, jsonpath

I have a JObject like this:

```
{
  name1: {
    value [
    ...
    ]
  }
}
```

It may also be in the form of:

```
{
  name2: {
    value [
    ...
    ]
  }
}
```

So I'm trying to use a single JSONPath to select the `JArray value` out. Is there a way to do something like this?

```
$['name1' or 'name2']['value']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers to these two SO questions: [OR operator in JSONPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897661/or-operator-in-jsonpath) and [JsonPath AND Operator on Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703891/jsonpath-and-operator-on-array), it seems `AND` and `OR` operators are not fully supported in JSONPath yet.

However, we can use the union operator to approximate what we need. Based on the [JSONPath documentation](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/),

```
Union operator in XPath results in a combination of node sets.
JSONPath allows alternate names or array indices as a set.
```

This seems to be what we need but still, [JsonPath AND Operator on Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703891/jsonpath-and-operator-on-array) mentioned the union operator may have some bugs or subtle differences between different implementations.

Similary, I've performed my own verification here: http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/.

I've tried `['name1','name2']['value']` and all but Nebhale's implementation correctly parses what I need. So I guess there is a solution to my original problem but it is a bit implementation-specific so please fully test your own code first to make sure this JSONPath and union operator will work in your code base.